# Excel OneDrive to Blob with Azure Data Factory

Tags: excel, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, onedrive

Has anyone ever done the Azure Data Factory flow activity copying Excel data on OneDrive to Azure Blob?

I can't do with logic app, because it will cost extra for it.

thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time there is no connector in ADF which can help us achieve your requirement but there is another way you can approach i.e., with the help of Power Automate using template or creating your own flow. Please use this link to get this address [Copy new files to AzureBlob from a OneDrive for Business folder](https://preview.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/49933434732d4846a1fc0aaae72f8998/copy-new-files-to-azureblob-from-a-onedrive-for-business-folder/).

[image]

Save it and Test Flow Manually under Test.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/464671/copy-files-from-onedrive-and-transfer-to-azure-blo.html

Comment: Sorry, for now we cannot using microsoft flow, logic apps or power automate .. because it is extra cost to provide it .. btw thanks for your sharing